# Best way to use indexes on large mysql like query

Tags: mysql, ajax, query-optimization, sql-like

This mysql query is runned on a large (about 200 000 records, 41 columns) myisam table :

select t1.* from `table` t1 where 1 and t1.`inactive` = '0' and (t1.`code` like '%searchtext%' or t1.`name` like '%searchtext%' or t1.`ext` like '%searchtext%' ) order by t1.`id` desc LIMIT 0, 15

id is the primary index.

I tried adding a multiple column index on all 3 searched (like) columns. works ok but results are served on a auto filled ajax table on a website and the 2 seond return delay is a bit too slow.

I also tried adding seperate indexes on all 3 columns and a fulltext index on all 3 columns without significant improvement.

What would be the best way to optimize this type of query? I would like to achieve under 1 sec performance, is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is implement paging.  No matter what you do, that IO cost is going to be huge.  If you only return one page of records, 10/25/ or whatever that will help a lot.

As for the index, you need to check the plan to see if your index is actually being used.  A full text index might help but that depends on how many rows you return and what you pass in.  Using parameters such as % really drain performance.  You can still use an index if it ends with % but not starts with %.  If you put % on both sides of the text you are searching for, indexes can't help too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a full-text index that covers the three columns: `code`, `name`, and `ext`.  Then perform a full-text query using the `MATCH() AGAINST ()` function:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
where match(code, name, ext) against ('searchtext')
order by t1.id desc
limit 0, 15
```

If you omit the `ORDER BY` clause the rows are sorted by default using the `MATCH` function result relevance value.  For more information read the [Full-Text Search Functions documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

As @Vulcronos notes, the query optimizer is not able to use the index when the `LIKE` operator is used with an expression that starts with a wildcard `%`.